# Javascript function not working after validation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

Currently doing a function whereby users can input their enquiries which will be sent to the database and retrieved by the admin, but the function of adding enquiry stopped working after i added a validation code, the problem lies in the validation but i cant seem to find the error.

My js code:

```
var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
var Texttitle;
var Textenquiry;

function validate() {
    var validate = true;

    if (Texttitle == "") {
        alert("Title cannot be empty");
        $("#Texttitle").focus();
        validate = false;
    }

    if (Textenquiry == "") {
        alert("Enquiry cannot be empty");
        $("#Textenquiry").focus();
        validate = false;
    }


    return validate;
}


function addenquiry() {

    Texttitle = $("#Texttitle").val();
    Textenquiry = $("#Textenquiry").val();

    if (validate()) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = serverURL() + "/addenquiry.php";
        url += "?userid=" + userid + "&Texttitle=" + Texttitle + "&Textenquiry=" + Textenquiry;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            addEnquiry(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

function addEnquiry(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    if (arr[0].result == 1) {
        alert("Thank You for your enquiry!")
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry please try again");
    }

}
```

My Html:

```
 <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
     <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Texttitle">Title</label>
       <input class="mdl-textfield__input" rows="2" type="text" id="Texttitle">
 </div>
    <br>
    <br>
 <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
       <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Textenquiry">Message</label>
         <input class="mdl-textfield__input" rows="2" type="text" id="Textenquiry">
 </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-color--primary mdl-js-button mdl-color-text--white full-width" onclick="addenquiry()">Submit</button>
 <div class="material-icons mdl-badge mdl-badge--overlap">�</div>
```

My function was running well previously before i entered the validation codes in, after my attempt at validating, the function is unable to send enquiries into my database, would appreciate some help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have a few syntax errors. First you are redefining your validate function inside itself (probably should just called the variable something different like 'validated'. However, your main issue is just that you are missing the closing brace on your addenquiry method. I'd also suggest making your method names more unique and not just changing the case of the names as debugging that kind of thing can be a nightmare as your code grows.

Try this:

```
        var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
    var Texttitle;
    var Textenquiry;

    function validate() {
        var validated = true;

        if (Texttitle == "") {
            alert("Title cannot be empty");
            $("#Texttitle").focus();
            validated = false;
        }

        if (Textenquiry == "") {
            alert("Enquiry cannot be empty");
            $("#Textenquiry").focus();
            validated = false;
        }


        return validated;
    }


    function addenquiry() {

        Texttitle = $("#Texttitle").val();
        Textenquiry = $("#Textenquiry").val();

        if (validate()) {

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = serverURL() + "/addenquiry.php";
            url += "?userid=" + userid + "&Texttitle=" + Texttitle + "&Textenquiry=" + Textenquiry;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                addEnquiry(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }

    function addEnquiry(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        if (arr[0].result == 1) {
            alert("Thank You for your enquiry!")
        }
        else {
            alert("Sorry please try again");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works fine now, will keep your comments as a learning point!

Answer (score 0):

In your validate function, why have you duplicated your logic? You have:

```
if (Texttitle == "") {
    alert("Title cannot be empty");
    $("#Texttitle").focus();
    validate = false;

} if (Textenquiry == "") {
    alert("Enquiry cannot be empty");
    $("#Textenquiry").focus();
    validate = false;
}
```

twice.

Also, your issue may be the `*/` at the end of your validate function

Comment: Thank you for pointing them out, i was testing it previously and forgot to remove them before posting it here, even after removing as mentioned, code still doesn't work. Edited question already.